# How to compare the elements from one array in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If any of the `choice` object from `choices` array is not found in any of the `results` array hide `choice` element in this case `{"choice": "f"}` and `{"choice": "g"}` is not available in any of those 3 results so I need to hide it. How can I do it?

```
{"choices":[
    {"choice": "a"},
    {"choice": "b"},
    {"choice": "c"},
    {"choice": "d"},
    {"choice": "e"},
    {"choice": "f"},
    {"choice": "g"}
],
"results":[
    {"result":["a", "b", "c"]},             
    {"result":["a", "b", "d"]},
    {"result":["a", "b", "e"]},
```

Comment: what means *hide*? do you need an array with the result?

Comment: the question is unclear, the posted code is just a cut chunk of some code with no beginning and ending(voted to close)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect all values from result and filter choices.

```js
var object = { choices: [{ choice: "a" }, { choice: "b" }, { choice: "c" }, { choice: "d" }, { choice: "e" }, { choice: "f" }, { choice: "g" }], results: [{ result: ["a", "b", "c"] }, { result: ["a", "b", "d"] }, { result: ["a", "b", "e"] }] },
    hash = Object.create(null),
    notIn = [];

object.results.forEach(function (a) {
    a.result.forEach(function (b) {
        hash[b] = true;
    });
});

notIn = object.choices.filter(function (a) {
    return !hash[a.choice];
});

console.log(notIn);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var object = { choices: [{ choice: "a" }, { choice: "b" }, { choice: "c" }, { choice: "d" }, { choice: "e" }, { choice: "f" }, { choice: "g" }], results: [{ result: ["a", "b", "c"] }, { result: ["a", "b", "d"] }, { result: ["a", "b", "e"] }] },
    results = object.results.reduce((s, a) => new Set([...s, ...a.result]), new Set),
    notIn = object.choices.filter(a => !results.has(a.choice));

console.log(notIn);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: +1 for the ```Set``` solution, maybe opting for ```let``` instead of ```var``` would be better for a full ES6 solution?

Comment: @Anis, actually the scope is not the problem.

Comment: I completely agree, and since it doesn't matter I just thought that let would be a better default in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you are asking for generic implementation ideas, or pointers as to how to implement it in javascript. I'll go for the general idea. You can simply use a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store all the possible results, then iterate through the choices and check for each choice whether it is inside the set. If not, you can take the action you want like hiding it, whatever that means.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` on data.choices and then `some()` and `includes()` to check if choice exists in some of the objects in results array.

```js
var data = {"choices":[{"choice":"a"},{"choice":"b"},{"choice":"c"},{"choice":"d"},{"choice":"e"},{"choice":"f"},{"choice":"g"}],"results":[{"result":["a","b","c"]},{"result":["a","b","d"]},{"result":["a","b","e"]}]}

data.choices = data.choices.filter(function(o, i) {
  var check = data.results.some(e => e.result.includes(o.choice))
  return check;
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var choices = {choices:[{choice:"a"},{choice:"b"},{choice:"c"},{choice:"d"},{choice:"e"},{choice:"f"},{choice:"g"}],results:[{result:["a","b","c"]},{result:["a","b","d"]},{result:["a","b","e"]}]},

    elems1 = choices.results.map(v => v.result).reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b)),
    filtered = [...new Set(elems1)];
    choices.choices = choices.choices.filter(v => filtered.some(c => c == v.choice) );
    console.log(choices);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information. This seems to be becoming a theme here, @Kinduser...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Actually I don't want to write anything because this is over complicated... I will wait for Nina response and I will decide to leave or to delete my answer. If I will decide to leave it, I will describe each step.

Comment: @Kinduser, you could reduce with `Set`, instead of mapping the values.

Comment: @NinaScholz Can you show me an example? Just a short one.

Comment: @Kinduser, please see my es6 example.